# Sifrei Neviim that don't make it to the haftarot

Tags: navi-prophets, haftarah

Which *seforim* in *navi* are not in any of the *Haftarot*?

Comment: This question would be a great deal more valuable if you would [edit] in information about why you want to know the answer.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/48244/440

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We read Haftarot from all the 8 Nevi'im scrolls, at various times during the year. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haftarah) for a list.

Three of the *12 minor prophets* - תְּרֵי עֲשַׂר - are not included in any Haftarah.

- Nachum - נחום
- Zefania - צפניה
- Chagai - חגי

Comment: In the old three-year style system in Israel even those three books were used. Also notable is even nowadays Havakkuk is only ever read from in the Diaspora.